# Only one character is displayed while using python3.5 web crawler

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python.I try to do some experiments using python3.5 web crawler.Here is my code:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import re

for x in range(1):
    page = x+1
    url = "http://www.last.fm/tag/female+vocalists/artists?page="+str(page)
    try:
        data=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
        data=data.decode('UTF-8')
        #reg = r'<p class="grid-items-item-main-text">.*?link-block-target">'
        #'(.*?)</a>.*?aux-text">"(.*?)"<span class="stat-name"'
        reg = r'<p class="grid-items-(.*?)-main-text'
        pattern = re.compile(reg, re.S)
        items = pattern.findall(data)
        for item in items:
            #print(item[0],item[1])
            print(item[0])
    except URLError as e:
        print('We failed to reach a server.')
        print('Reason: ', e.reason)
```

But I am disappointed to find that only one character `i` is displayed.It supposed to display `item`.

Where is the problem? Please help me! Thanks!

I try to solve the problem according to the answers to the question. It really works! But I have a new question! I modified the code as follows:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import re

for x in range(1):
    page = x+1
    url = "http://www.last.fm/tag/female+vocalists/artists?page="+str(page)
    try:
        data=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
        data=data.decode('UTF-8')
        reg = r'class=\"link-block-target\"[\r\n]+.*?>.*?</a>[\r\n]+.*?</p>'
        '[\r\n]+.*?<p class=\"grid-items-item-aux-text\">[\r\n]+.*?'
        '<span class=\"stat-name\">'
        pattern = re.compile(reg, re.S)
        items = pattern.findall(data)
        for item in items:
            print(item)
    except URLError as e:
        print('We failed to reach a server.')
        print('Reason: ', e.reason)
```

And I found that it still inputs something althongh there is no `(.*?)` in the 
regular expression. Where is the problem lies? Thanks!

I solved my problem finally. It attributes to error representation multi-line string. Here is the new code:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import re

for x in range(1):
    page = x+1
    url = "http://www.last.fm/tag/female+vocalists/artists?page="+str(page)
    try:
        data=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
        data=data.decode('UTF-8')
        reg = (r'class=\"link-block-target\"[\r\n]+.*?>(.*?)</a>[\r\n]+.*?</p>'
        '[\r\n]+.*?<p class=\"grid-items-item-aux-text\">[\r\n]+(.*?)'
        '<span class=\"stat-name\">')
        pattern = re.compile(reg, re.S)
        items = pattern.findall(data)
        for item in items:
            print(item[0],item[1])
    except URLError as e:
        print('We failed to reach a server.')
        print('Reason: ', e.reason)
```

Thank everyone for helping me solve the problem!

Comment: Just `print(item)`. Not sure why you have the `[0]`.

Comment: @AlexHall If I want to get two strings,how should I print?

Comment: That's when you would use `print(item[0],item[1])`.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the first element of 'item'

```
for item in items:
    #print(item[0],item[1])
    print(item) # not item[0]
```

Comment: If I want to get two strings, like `reg = r'<p class="grid-items-(.*?)-main-text(.*?)</p>'`, what should I do to print them both?

Answer (score 0):

First I think in your regular expression you are missing the escape for `"`

`reg = r'<p class=\"grid-items-(.*?)-main-text'`

Then, if you want to print both results, you were doing it fine with `print(item[0],item[1])`, but as I see on the html code of the web you are trying to scrape, if you just want the actual text (title of the song for example) you should work a bit more on your regular expression, or use another library like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) were you will find more powerful and easy ways to get the elements you need.